# C++: Most efficient and concise way to access a heavy member variable in a large dataset

Tags: c++, performance

I have a class such as `A` that contains a non-trivial member variable of type `LargeType`:

```
class A {
public:
    LargeType SetVariable(LargeType var){_var = var;}
    LargeType GetVariable(){return _var;}
private:
    LargeType _var;
};
```

I loop through a very large dataset and retrieve an object `a` of type `A` in every iteration. I have found that the following code (which occurs at least once per iteration):

```
//---- Version#1
LargeType var = a.GetVariable();
if(anotherLargeType == var){ DoSomething();}
DoOperation(var);
```

runs slower than the following code:

```
//---- Version#2
if(anotherLargeType == a1.GetVariable();){ DoSomething();}
DoOperation(a1.GetVariable());
```

I can appreciate why Version#1 runs slower than Version#2: a copy constructor is called in every iteration, so more work is done. However, I would argue that Version#1 is nicer to deal with, rather than having to type out `a1.GetVariable()` multiple times in one loop. Is there a way to rewrite my class so that the performance of Version#1 and Version#2 are comparable?

Comment: With the code you have written, I don't understand how Version 2 is faster than Version 1. Each time you call `A::GetVariable` you are calling a copy constructor and Version 2 calls `A::GetVariable` twice. Unless the compiler is doing some optimization I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return a reference to your member variable. Doing so, you don't waste time creating and/or copying temporaries:

```
class A {
public:
    void SetVariable(const LargeType& var){_var = var;}
    LargeType& GetVariable(){return _var;}
    const LargeType& GetVariable() const {return _var;}
private:
    LargeType _var;
};
```

As you can see, I added a `const` version of `GetVariable`; that's to make it possible to call the method on objects of type `const A` and `const A&`.

To avoid creating unwanted copies, you must use references in the calling code too:

```
//---- Version#1
LargeType& var = a.GetVariable();
if(anotherLargeType == var){ DoSomething();}
DoOperation(var);
```

Comment: For completeness I think you should show how the calling code should look to take advantage of these references. Otherwise, OP could still write  "Version#1" make a copy and gain no advantage.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Fair enough :)