# Ways to return an object in C++ method

Tags: c++, class, object, reference

Say I have a class that looks like this

```
class MyAnimals{
public:
    Animal getAnimal(int index){
        return animals.at(index);
    }
private:
    vector<Animal> animals;
}
```

From what I've learned about C++ so far, I think `getAnimal` currently returns a copy of the animal, not a reference like in Java. I've seen this suggested as the correct way to go about returning objects, but what if you want to modify that animal once it's returned? I'd just be changing the copy of it and the actual animal inside of MyAnimals.animals would remain unchanged. One way I've seen to get around this is to return `Animal&` instead of `Animal`, and that seems to work for the most part, but what if I want to reassign the variable the was assigned to that returned Animal? For example,

```
Animal& a = myanimals.getAnimal(1);
a = myanimals.getAnimal(2);
```

From what I get, this would change the animal at `myanimals.animals[1]` to be the same exact object as `myanimals.animals[2]`, since a was a reference. What are the different ways to go about returning objects?

Comment: It depends on the desired semantics. Which you haven't fully specified.

Comment: Answered something similar today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734938/c-most-efficient-and-concise-way-to-access-a-heavy-member-variable-in-a-large/32735003#32735003

Comment: If you need to modify private data outisde of the class, why did you make it private in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From what I've learned about C++ so far, I think getAnimal currently returns a copy of the animal, not a reference like in Java.

Correct.

> I've seen this suggested as the correct way to go about returning objects

If you intend to return a copy, then yes.

> I'd just be changing the copy of it and the actual animal inside of MyAnimals.animals would remain unchanged.

Correct.

> One way I've seen to get around this is to return Animal& instead of Animal, and that seems to work for the most part

Yes, references are exactly what you need for that.

> but what if I want to reassign the variable the was assigned to that returned Animal?

Well, typically there is no need to do re-assign an existing reference  (which is not allowed anyway). Instead of what you did, you could do:

```
Animal& a = myanimals.getAnimal(1);
Animal& b = myanimals.getAnimal(2);
```

If you for some reason need to, then use a pointer instead, to get around the limitation. You can do this even when you return a reference:

```
Animal* a = &myanimals.getAnimal(1);
a = &myanimals.getAnimal(2);
```

Comment: It's also probably worth noting, as the comments to the question were hinting at, that often if you need to reference private data members outside of a class, there might be an architectural issue with how you've laid out your code. It's not a rule, there are definitely legitimate use-cases for wanting to do that, but it should at least make you ask the question "is there a better way to structure this?"

Comment: It's been awhile since I've worked in a Java/C++ like language, but isn't this general convention for OOP? Never directly accessing class properties and instead accessing them through getters and setters?

Comment: @Weston Yes, because you can provide validation (among other things) in your getter/setter functions.

Answer (score 1):

I know of the following ways to return an `Animal` from `MyAnimals`.

1. By `const` reference. This allows you to avoid making a copy when you need to just query the object.

   ```
   Animal const& getAnimal(int index) const;
   ```
2. By reference. This allows you to modify the object inside a `MyAnimals`.

   ```
   Animal& getAnimal(int index);
   ```
3. By value. This is the safest method to return an `Animal` as far as the contents of `MyAnimals` is concerned but is also the most inefficient.

   ```
   Animal getAnimal(int index) const;
   ```
4. Provide access to the elements through iterators.

   ```
   class MyAnimals
   {
      public:
         typedef vector<Animal>::iterator iterator;
         typedef vector<Animal>::const_iterator const_iterator;

         iterator begin();
         iterator end;

         const_iterator begin() const;
         const_iterator end const;

         Animal getAnimal(int index){
            return animals.at(index);
         }
      private:
         vector<Animal> animals;
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "reassign" a reference by design. But you can reassign a pointer. So if you have a `getAnimal()` that returns a reference you can write:

```
Animal* a = &myanimals.getAnimal(1);
a = &myanimals.getAnimal(2);
```

Comment: Yes It sounds like you want a variable "a" and you want to reassign that to different Objects in the myAnimals vector.  The solution from Chris is exactly how I would go about that by using pointers.